# How to create vector stripes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, patterns

I made a bar graph in Illustrator using Pattern Swatches for the diagonal stripes:

[image]

In Illustrator, this looks perfect and saves as a vector. However, this graph is going to be published, and apparently Pattern Swatches are problematic for some types of publishing (sometimes the pattern simply drops out, or fills solid, or even changes color).

Is there an easy way to make stripe fill like this without using Pattern Swatches?

Comment: re-draw the stripes, convert to object, and use the Pathfinder's shape mode tools

Comment: How do I convert to object?

Answer (score 1):

- Fill with a pattern
- `Object > Expand`

Then if you want.. `Pathfinder > Crop`

It's no longer a pattern, but individual objects in a group.

[image: expand]

(Optical illusion.. those are perfect squares, even though they look skewed. :) )

Comment: This looks like it gives individual squares of pattern swatches, rather than whole diagonal bar as an object.

Comment: It splits the live pattern into visible elements. The split occurs where the pattern tile occurs. This was a **very quick** pattern I just created to show the expansion. And if you don't want live pattern fills.. this is your only alternative other than rasterizing.